# How can I force a migration to not create stub nodes?

Tags: entities, migrations

I have multiple migrations that rely on one another for entity reference fields.  When I created the queries these migrations I made sure I was only getting the nodes I want.  When an entity id is given and was not previously migrated (because the query did not return it as a result), it creates a stub node.  Then the number of unprocessed nodes for that node migration go into the negatives because more nodes of those types were imported than I had returned in the query.  Now I have to run update migrations because there is a newer version of the legacy database available.  The problem is that because the number of unprocessed went into the negatives, I cannot import any more, it just defaults to 0.

So how do I force entity reference fields to not import if it doesn't exist in the new site?